# How to make a variable CSS transition delay with variable number of elements?

Tags: css, angular, sass, css-animations

I have the following animation

```
.slide-top {
  animation: slide-top 1s /* variable transition-delay here */ cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.46, 0.45, 0.94) both;
}

@keyframes slide-top {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(-60px);
  }
}
```

and here is my Angular template

```
<div *ngFor="let service of services" class="slide-top">
  <div class="services">
    <h4>{{service.title | translate}}</h4>
    <p>{{service.description | translate}}</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

I need something like this

```
.slide-top { //For first element
  animation: slide-top 1s 0ms cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.46, 0.45, 0.94) both;
}

.slide-top { //For second element
  animation: slide-top 1s 100ms cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.46, 0.45, 0.94) both;
}

...
```

I could have tried `:nth-child()` pseudo-class, but i don't know the number of elements in the array, and that's not practical anyway.

Your help is appreciated.

Comment: May this  help https://css-tricks.com/different-approaches-for-creating-a-staggered-animation/

Comment: You could set a CSS variable, say --delay, which depends on the index in the div declaration via style attribute then use that in the animation setting.

Comment: **@ServeshChaturvedi** - Thank you very much, that really helped, what i needed was that `--animation-order` property to be set on every element with a value of `i`, and in my css class I added `calc(var(--animation-order) * 200ms)` so the property now became this: **`animation: slide-top 0.8s calc(var(--animation-order) * 200ms) cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.46, 0.45, 0.94) both;`**.